# Updating WYSIWYG summernote content breaks the images

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

I am using summernote WYSIWYG editor and I don't have any trouble creating or viewing its content but I do get broken images when updating the content. As in not just a broken link but an image with 0 bytes gets saved.

When I try to update it I get the undefined offset 1 error because of the explode function, but when I tried to fix it I get the broken image problem.

Here's my text editor content parser:

```
/*
     * @param $content is request data from wysiwyg
     * @param $directory is where to save the images
     */
    public function parseTextEditorContent($content, $directory)
    {
        $dom = new \domdocument();
        $dom->loadHtml($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        $images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');

        //loop over img elements, decode their base64 src and save them to public folder,
        //and then replace base64 src with stored image URL.
        foreach($images as $k => $img){
            $data = $img->getattribute('src');

            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
            list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

            $data = base64_decode($data);
            $image_name= time().$k.'.png';
            $path = public_path().'/img/'.$directory.'/'.$image_name;
            $src = '/img/'.$directory.'/'.$image_name;

            file_put_contents($path, $data);

            $img->removeattribute('src');
            $img->setattribute('src', $src);
        }

        $content = $dom->savehtml();
        return $content;
    }
```

Also here's an example of my content sa a base64 string.

```
<p>Porro esse ipsa, ali.</p><p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" data-filename="19598644_1899832350030685_6042892852142940235_n.jpg" style="width: 160px;"><br></p>
```

Comment: Do you have an example `$content`? See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You do know you're restricting the image type to PNG?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I do know that, and like I said it doesn't create a problem while creating the post, only when updating it, even if it's updating with the same data.
The content would be something like this : `<p><img data-filename="19598644_1899832350030685_6042892852142940235_n.jpg" style="width: 160px;" src="/img/post_photos/15640438640.png"><p>Fuga. Odio illum, oc.</p></p>`

Comment: Could you put the example of `$content` in your question? Please make sure it is accurate, and not just somewhat like the real thing. I was expecting a base64 string.

Comment: I ran the code in your question, with the example in your question, and the correct content is in `$data` when you're saving it. Are you sure it _actually creates_ the file, but that the size of the file is zero? I could understand a situation where no file was created at all.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 100% certain. On store method it creates it and works as expected,but on update method it creates a 0 byte image.

Comment: My guess would be, and I can only guess, is that the `$content` is different when you use the "update method".

Answer (score 2):

You can check the image is base 64 or not ,inside the loop then update only if the image is Base64

```
 $editor_content=$request->editor_content;
$dom = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml($editor_content);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$bs64='base64';//variable to check the image is base64 or not
foreach ($images as $k => $img) {
        $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
        if (strpos($data,$bs64) == true)//if the Image is base 64
         {
        $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
        $image_name = "/storage/blog/". 'post_' . time() . $k . '.png';
        $path = public_path() . $image_name;
        file_put_contents($path, $data);
        $img->removeAttribute('src');
        $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
        }
        else//put '/' to prevent lossing image  actual path
        {
            $image_name="/".$data;
            $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
        }
      };
 
$editor_content_save= $dom->saveHTML();
// return $editor_content_save;
$slug = Str::slug($request->title,'-');
$blog = Blog::where('id', $request->blog_id)->first();
$blog->title = $request->title;
$blog->author = $request->author;
$blog->tags=collect($request->tags)->implode(',');
$blog->content = $editor_content_save;
$blog->slug = $slug;
$blog->date = $request->date;
$blog->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $content=$Guide->input('MainContent');
    $dom = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHtml($content);
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $bs64='base64';
    foreach ($images as $i => $img) {
            $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
            if (strpos($data,$bs64) == true)
             {
            $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
            $image_name = '/images/userguide/'. time() . $i . '.png';
            $path = public_path() . $image_name;
            file_put_contents($path, $data);
            $img->removeAttribute('src');
            $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
            }
            else
            {
                $image_name=$data;
                $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
            }
          }

    $content_save= $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: why @balwinder sing Sohi Pasted my answer here??